# I try to make 4 GradientFills in actionscript3 use the same codes, but two of them work, the other two don't

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to draw four shapes and fill them with gradient fills, but only two of them display as I expect, the other two don't work. The question is, I use exactly the same codes for four gradient fills.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.display.GradientType;  

drawBackground();

function drawBackground():void{
var ground:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(ground);
ground.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x999999);
ground.graphics.beginFill(0xE6E6E6, 0.5);
ground.graphics.drawRect(0,0,640,610);
ground.graphics.endFill();
ground.x = 30;
ground.y = 60;

var mat:Matrix;  
var color:Array;
var alphas:Array;
var ratio:Array;

mat=new Matrix(); 
color=[0xD5D5D5,0x999999];
alphas=[0.5, 0.8];
ratio=[0,255];

var topwall:Sprite=new Sprite();
mat.createGradientBox(700,60,Math.PI/2);
topwall.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x999999);
topwall.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, color, alphas, ratio, mat);
topwall.graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
topwall.graphics.lineTo(700, 0);
topwall.graphics.lineTo(670, 60);
topwall.graphics.lineTo(30,60);
this.addChild(topwall);

var leftwall:Sprite=new Sprite();
mat.createGradientBox(30,700,0);
leftwall.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x999999);
leftwall.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, color, alphas, ratio, mat);
leftwall.graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
leftwall.graphics.lineTo(0,700);
leftwall.graphics.lineTo(30, 670);
leftwall.graphics.lineTo(30,60);
this.addChild(leftwall);

var bottomwall:Sprite=new Sprite();
mat.createGradientBox(700,700,-Math.PI/2);
bottomwall.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x999999);
bottomwall.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, color, alphas, ratio, mat);
bottomwall.graphics.moveTo(30, 670);
bottomwall.graphics.lineTo(670,670);
bottomwall.graphics.lineTo(700, 700);
bottomwall.graphics.lineTo(0,700);
this.addChild(bottomwall);

var rightwall:Sprite=new Sprite();
mat.createGradientBox(30,700,0);
rightwall.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x999999);
rightwall.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, color, alphas, ratio, mat);
rightwall.graphics.moveTo(670, 60);
rightwall.graphics.lineTo(670,670);
rightwall.graphics.lineTo(700, 700);
rightwall.graphics.lineTo(700,0);
this.addChild(rightwall);
}
```

Well at present topwall and leftwall behave properly but the rest two are filled with single color. Anyone may know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some tweaks to createGradientBox:

```
var bottomwall:Sprite=new Sprite();
mat.createGradientBox(700,30,-Math.PI/2, 0, 670);
bottomwall.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x999999);
bottomwall.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, color, alphas, ratio, mat);
bottomwall.graphics.moveTo(30, 670);
bottomwall.graphics.lineTo(670,670);
bottomwall.graphics.lineTo(700, 700);
bottomwall.graphics.lineTo(0,700);
this.addChild(bottomwall);

var rightwall:Sprite=new Sprite();
mat.createGradientBox(30,700,Math.PI, 670, 0);
rightwall.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x999999);
rightwall.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, color, alphas, ratio, mat);
rightwall.graphics.moveTo(670, 60);
rightwall.graphics.lineTo(670,670);
rightwall.graphics.lineTo(700, 700);
rightwall.graphics.lineTo(700,0);
this.addChild(rightwall);
```

Comment: Many thanks! It works now, however, I am still not sure why I have to specify tx and ty values here. I left them blank when writing topwall and leftwall and they worked properly.

Comment: its because you are not drawing from position 0,0 - the gradient starts from 0,0 point by default so it needs to be translated to (eg) 670,0.